# Remove columns with many NA values using mlr3pipelines

Tags: r, mlr3

I am trying to remove columns where proportion of NA value are greater than na_cutoff threshold using mlr3pipelines.

Here is my try:

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3pipelines)

task = tsk("iris")
dt = task$data()
dt[1:50, Sepal.Width := NA]
task_ = as_task_classif(dt, target = "Species")

graph = po("removeconstants", id = "removeconstants", ratio = 0.01) %>>%
  po("select", id = "drop_na_cols")
ps = ParamSet$new(list(ParamDbl$new("na_cutoff", lower = 0, upper = 1, default = 0.2)))
graph$param_set$add(ps)
graph$param_set
graph$param_set$trafo = function(x, param_set) {
  na_cutoff = x$na_cutoff
  print(na_cutoff)
  x$drop_na_cols.selector = function(task) {
    fn = task$feature_names
    data = task$data(cols = fn)
    drop <- which(colMeans(is.na(data)) > na_cutoff)
    fn[-drop]
  }
  x$na_cutoff = NULL
  x
}
train_res = graph$train(task_)
train_res$drop_na_cols.output$data()
```

The problem is that last column is not removed even it should be.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `trafo`s are not meant for parameter sets.
I.e. internally, when the `Graph` accesses the parameters, the parameter transformation is not applied.
They are intended to create search spaces for black-box optimization, including hyperparameter optimization of ML models.

Also, you modifying the parameter set of an existing `Graph` is a bad idea.

The way to go I believe is to use the `PipeOpSelect` with a custom selector: https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/reference/Selector.html

Answer (score 0):

Following this issue https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3pipelines/issues/313
I thought the recommended way to do this is through trafo on select pipe.

Nevertheless, I have just created new pipeop that removes columns with many NA values:

```
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3verse)
library(mlr3misc)
library(R6)

PipeOpDropNACol = R6::R6Class(
  "PipeOpDropNACol",
  inherit = mlr3pipelines::PipeOpTaskPreprocSimple,
  public = list(
    initialize = function(id = "drop.nacol", param_vals = list()) {
      ps = ParamSet$new(list(
        ParamDbl$new("cutoff", lower = 0, upper = 1, default = 0.05, tags = c("dropnacol_tag"))
      ))
      ps$values = list(cutoff = 0.2)
      super$initialize(id, param_set = ps, param_vals = param_vals)
    }
  ),

  private = list(
    .get_state = function(task) {
      pv = self$param_set$get_values(tags = "dropnacol_tag")
      print(pv$cutoff)
      features_names = task$feature_names
      data = task$data(cols = features_names)
      print(data)
      many_na = sapply(data, function(column) (sum(is.na(column))) / length(column) > pv$cutoff)
      print(many_na)
      list(cnames = colnames(data)[-many_na])
    },

    .transform = function(task) {
      task$select(self$state$cnames)
    }
  )
)

# no group variable
task = tsk("iris")
dt = task$data()
dt[1:50, Sepal.Width := NA]
task = as_task_classif(dt, target = "Species")

gr = Graph$new()
gr$add_pipeop(PipeOpDropNACol$new())
result = gr$train(task)
result[[1]]$data()
gr$predict(task)
```